# Proof the concatenation of ordered list is an ordered list in Stainless

Tags: scala, formal-verification, stainless

I have the following code for sorting arrays which I want to verify in Stainless (previously known as Leon):

```
import stainless.lang._
import stainless.collection._

object QuickSort {

  def isSorted(list: List[BigInt]): Boolean = list match {
    case Cons(x, xs @ Cons(y, _)) => x <= y && isSorted(xs)
    case _ => true
  }

  def quickSort(list: List[BigInt]): List[BigInt] = (list match {
        case Nil() => Nil[BigInt]()
        case Cons(x, xs) => par(x, Nil(), Nil(), xs)
  }) ensuring { res => isSorted(res) }


  def par(x: BigInt, l: List[BigInt], r: List[BigInt], ls: List[BigInt]): List[BigInt] = {
    require(l.forall(_ <= x) && r.forall(_ >= x))
    ls match {
      case Nil() => quickSort(l) ++ Cons(x, quickSort(r))
      case Cons(x2, xs2) => if (x2 <= x) par(x, Cons(x2, l), r, xs2) else par(x, l, Cons(x2, r), xs2)
    }
  } ensuring {res => isSorted(res)}
}
```

I have plenty of directions to go from here (as it doesn't succeed to verify) however it seems to me that the verification should succeed with the hints provided and I want to know why it doesn't. I explain myself:

Apparently for verifying par function I need to proof that the two cases imply the isSorted postcondition separately. Now as the second case contains a recursive call then is evident that it implies the postcondition. For the first case of par, we have that the left and right subarrays are sorted and the precondition tells me that all the elements are sorted with respect to the pivot.

This last bit should imply in my opinion that the concatenating list is sorted as well. So why does it not verify? How could instruct Stainless to verify it? Do I need to add hints on the length and size to facilitate the task to Stainless?

**Edit:**

```
def concatIsSorted(l1 : List[BigInt],l2 : List[BigInt],pivot : BigInt) : Boolean = {
    require(isSorted(l1) && isSorted(l2) && l1.forall(_ <= pivot) && l2.forall(_ >= pivot))
    isSorted(l1 ++ Cons(pivot,l2)) because{
      l1 match{
        case Nil() => isSorted(Cons(pivot,l2))
        case Cons(h,Nil()) => h <= pivot && isSorted(Cons(pivot,l2))
        case Cons(h,t) => h <= t.head && concatIsSorted(t,l2,pivot)
      }     
    }   
  }.holds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is [looks like](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/sav17:labs_02) a homework question, I will try to guide you towards the solution without giving it away.

First note that the program verifies if you replace the `Nil()` case in `par` with `case Nil() => Nil()`. This shows that the verifier is not able to prove that the result of `quickSort(l) ++ Cons(x, quickSort(r))` is sorted (but it manage to do it for `Nil()`!).

When `--debug=verification` is not sufficient to understand why the verifier is not able to prove you think it should, the way to proceed is to introduce extra functions where you can precisely state your expectations. For instance if you define:

```
def plusplus(l: List[BigInt], r: List[BigInt]): List[BigInt] = l ++ r
```

And annotate it with your what you expect the verifier to prove, that is

- Assuming `l` and `r` sorted and `l < r` (for the appropriate definition of `<`)
- The result of `l ++ r` is sorted

You will see that the verifier is not able to prove this property, meaning you need to guide the verification further with addition addition auxiliary functions, pre and postcondition.

Note that this example is taken from [*Dependent Types for Program Termination Verification*](https://www.cs.bu.edu/~hwxi/academic/papers/lics01.pdf), reading the paper might help you here.

Comment: your answer is helpful. just one question regarding the auxiliary function I wrote in the edit of my post. It is actually proven by stainless, do i need to do something so that it takes it into account in the proof of the postcondition of par?

Comment: Well, you need to use it! Refactor your `concatIsSorted` into a `(List[BigInt], List[BigInt]) => List[BigInt]` function (or equivalant) and use it instead of the original `++`.